# Django,how to filter multiple JSONField data?

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-filters, django-jsonfield

Im using django with postgres i was able to add multiple filters in my views but mu question here is is there any possibility that i can filter multiple same jsonfield with different values:
ex i can filter `localhost:127.0.0.1:products?areaOfUse=residential`
so is there any possibilty that i can get the result of  `/products?areaOfUse=residential&areaOfUse=test`
So from here i need to query two different json objects.

-Here are my views

```
class SubcategoriesProductsAPI(APIView):
    # @cache_control(must_revalidate=True, max_age=3600)
    def get (self, request, subCategoryId = None, pk = None):
        try:

            filters = {}
            design  = self.request.query_params.get('design', None)
            dimension = self.request.query_params.get('dimension', None)
            collectionName =  self.request.query_params.get('collectionName', None)
            material = self.request.query_params.get('material',None)
            min_price = self.request.query_params.get('min_price',None)
            max_price = self.request.query_params.get('max_price',None)
            page = self.request.query_params.get('page', None)
            wearLayer = self.request.query_params.get('wearLayer',None)
            areaOfUse = self.request.query_params.getlist('areaOfUse',None)
            productType = self.request.query_params.get('type', None)
            installationMethod =  self.request.query_params.get('installationMethod',None)
            format_type = self.request.query_params.get('format_type',None)
            wearLayer = self.request.query_params.get('wearLayer',None)
            levelOfUse = self.request.query_params.get('levelOfUse',None)

            if design is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__design'] = design

            if productType is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__type'] = productType
            
            if dimension is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__dimensions__contains'] = [{'dimension': dimension}]
           
            if collectionName is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__collectionName'] = collectionName
            
            if material is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__material'] = material

            if wearLayer is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__wearLayer'] = wearLayer

            if installationMethod is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__installationMethod'] =installationMethod 

            if format_type is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__format'] = format_type

            if areaOfUse is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__areaOfUse__contains'] = areaOfUse
                    

            if levelOfUse is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__levelOfUse'] = levelOfUse

            if min_price and max_price:
                filters['product_options__options__data__dimensions__range__price'] = float(min_price)
                filters['product_options__options__data__dimensions__0__price__lte'] = float(max_price)

                
            queryset = Products.objects.filter(sub_categories_id = subCategoryId, is_active = True).select_related().filter(**filters)
            
            if not queryset:
                return JsonResponse({ 'status': False, 'msg': 'No products found', 'data': {} }, status=400)
            
            if page is not None:
                paginator = PageNumberPagination()
                page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)

                if page is not None:
                    serializer = ProductSerializer(page, many=True)
                    return JsonResponse({ 'status': True, 'msg': 'Succesfully retrived products ', 'data': serializer.data,  'count': paginator.page.paginator.count, 'previous':paginator.get_previous_link(), 'next':paginator.get_next_link() }, status=200)
            serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return JsonResponse({ 'status': True, 'msg': 'Succesfully retrived products ', 'data': serializer.data }, status=200)
        except Products.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({ 'status': False, 'msg': 'Internal system error', 'data': {}}, status=500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
areaOfUse = self.request.query_params.getlist('areaOfUse[]',None)
```

> /products?areaOfUse%5B%5D=residential&areaOfUse%5B%5D=test

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
queryset = Products.objects.filter(sub_categories_id = subCategoryId, is_active = True).select_related().filter(**filters)
if areaOfUse:
    queryset.filter(
        reduce(
            operator.and_,
            (Q(product_options__options__data__areaOfUse__contains=x) for x in areaOfUse)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Still no luck in these case i dont get any result.Or should i change the contains with something different :`if areaOfUse is not None:
                filters['product_options__options__data__areaOfUse__contains'] = areaOfUse`

Comment: your areaOfUse var is a list

Comment: use operator.and_ or operator.or_ depending on your expected result.

Comment: I was able to fix thanks to @Agawane,his answer was very helpful.